# z3c RML to PDF extremely slow

Tags: django, pdf

I have a Django application and I am using z3c.rml for generating pdf. Converting to pdf for small data works fine. But when the data is large, the rmlparser takes forever to convert and times out.

I figured out that this line is the issue- **rml2pdf.parseString(rendered_template)**